# Entity Framework and problems with statelessness of the web

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

Is it better to avoid the Entity Framework when creating an ASP.NET Web Forms site because of the problems of statelessness of the Web? ViewState and Session do not support non-serializable classes like DBContext which sort of makes using the Entity Framework rather awkward.

Is the EF better suited to ASP.NET MVC because it doesn't rely on ViewState and Session?

Comment: There are reasons to avoid EF, but this isn't one of them. :) It's never a good practice to keep DB-connected objects alive between web requests (which can be minutes apart) - no matter what the platform. You theoretically "can" within in-memory Session, but again, not a good practice. You want to keep only "DTO" objects (please google) in Session/cache. Minimize ViewState as much as possible - it bloats page requests. Coming back to EF: it's powerful and usually used for larger applications. For something smaller, I'd recommend a library that's lighter-weight, like Dapper.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the two have nothing to do with each other.

The entity framework creates an abstraction for persisting information within a database.  Within a web app, its *state* exists for the duration of an HTTP request, and any pending changes are persisted when the response is ended.  EF does not require state information to be stored between postbacks, and thus viewstate and session state are irrelevant.  It's true that database connections may be kept open between requests, however that's managed by the connection pool or driver.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC does not rely on ViewState but it is still by default stateless. Anyway EF is supposed to be used with ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC but you must use a new context instance for every processed request. Any effort to "store" context among requests is only way to disaster.